# Spring Boot not able to pick value from yml file

Tags: spring-boot, yaml

I have a application-local.yml file inside resources folder. I have some properties like
`data: https://xyzw/`
I am using this property in a different class

```
  @Service
    public class Test {
    @Value("${data}")
    private String data;
    
    }
```

When I run the Application.java I get the following error:
`Application.main(Application.java:13), exception_class=org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException, exception_message=Error creating bean with name 'Test': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'data' in value "${data}"}","threadID":"main","sourceHost":"H18NPLFI13P0303","logVersion":"1.5","category":"org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication"}`
Which is weird. I am not sure why it's not picking the values from the application-local.yml file.

Comment: Please add how you start your application. Via console or IDE? What command / which environment variables are set?

Comment: Does you application at startup use `local` profile?

Comment: @times29 I start it using Intellij Idea. By Running the Application.java file

Comment: @artiomi How do I check that? Since there is only one .yml file I was assuming it should pick that. This was working some commits back. I am trying to go back to an earlier working commit and make changes again to see when it breaks

Answer (score 0):

If you start your application with IntelliJ IDEA and want the `application-local.yml` properties to be used, you need to edit your run configuration so that the `local` profile is used, else the `application-local.yml` properties won't be picked up by Spring.

[image]